# Powershell function to add users to AD group from CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm building a script to automate AD deployments for customers. We have a prepared list of users and groups in CSV files. The groups are organized in a file with the following format. Keep in mind that I'm using the same CSV file to create the AD groups (which happens in a previous step).

```
Name,Description,Members
GroupName,GroupDescription,"user1,user2,user3"
```

The code I'm using to add the users to the groups is below:

```
$groups = Import-CSV -Path $groupCSVPath
$groups | % { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name -Members $_.Members }
```

This results in an error: *Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'user1,user2,user3'*.

If I attempt the following, it works:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "GroupName" -Members user1,user2,user3
```

The error appears to reference the Get-ADUser command, which does not accept arrays as inputs. However, the Add-ADGroupMember command does. Why am I getting the Get-ADUser error when using the Add-ADGroupMember command and how can I get it to accept an array of values for the AD Username?

Comment: It looks like your CSV file is really a list of lists.  Each entry in the CSV file contains one GroupName, one GroupDescription, and a list of users.  Right?  There is a way to "normalize" this data so that each entry contains a GroupName,GroupDescription, and exactly one User.  More entries, less data in each entry.  However, I'm not posting this as an answer, because it has a serious downside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky one. The problem turned out to be that the `$_.members` parameter is being passed to the `Add-ADGroupMember` cmdlet as a single string rather than an array of separate values, because of the way `Import-CSV` works. `Get-Help Add-ADGroupMember` shows that the `members` parameter expects an array, not a string.

This should work, I've tested it:

`$groups | % { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name -Members $_.members.split(',') }`

Comment: Yeah, it was tricky, but the folks here on SO came to the rescue again. Thanks!